# RUBY HASH within Hash ;no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, erb

I'm trying to resolve a type error, but i'm not sure where the error would be. i am making assumptions that it would be in my client.rb file. I am trying to fill in an ERB file with the correct ip address based on whether its location A or location B. If its in location A then take the first IP address and fill it in, then on another line do the same with the second IP address for location A

Data Bag/ JSON

```
{
  "id": "sources",
   "A": {"primary": "127.0.0.1", "secondary": "127.0.0.2"},
   "B": {"primary": "127.0.0.1", "secondary": "127.0.0.2"}
}
```

ERB FILE

```
:server <%=sources["primary"]%>
:server <%=sources["secondary"]%>
```

Client Recipe

```
data_bag = search(:win_sources,'id:sources')
case servername
when /^smd(.*)/
  sources = data_bag["B"]
...
end
```

Comment: There is an obvious error in your code. Your hash has no `sources` key. It has a `sources` **value**. So `<% sources[ "primary"] %>` makes no sense at all.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida This is a red herring. The sources variable is set with `data_bag["B"]` which *is included* in the data bag.

Comment: Oh I see @HolgerJust. My talking comes too fast to my thoughts sometimes! Thank you.

Comment: Not an answer but for your erb you want to add `=` signs or you won't see anything even when it does work. e.g. `:server <%= sources["primary"] %>`. in simple terms `<%=` means render the output from the interpretation and `<%` means interpret but do not render.

Answer (score 2):

Chef's `search` method always returns an array of matches. Thus, your `data_bag` variable probably contains an array with a single element: your intended hash.

You can normalize this by using something like this:

```
data_bags = search(:win_sources,'id:sources')
if data_bags.size == 1
  data_bag = data_bags.first
else
  raise 'More or less than one sources data bag found!'
end
```